# How can Serialize XML in Android?

Tags: android, xml, regex

I'm getting a text in **XML** Format with **Soap** Serivce and now I want to split an Image tag and a Video Tag in different Serialize format.

My text :

```
<Images> 
<Image ImageID="1000032" StoredFilename="42825125-8002-4d28-ba90-9889de5e4e91.jpg" ImageName="bPanda"  /></Images>
<PlayLists><PlayList PlayListID="1000005"  />
</PlayLists><PlayListVideoXrefs>
<PlayListVideoXref PlayListVideoXrefID="1000027" PlayListID="1000005" VideoID="1000006" PlayOrder="1"  />
<PlayListVideoXref PlayListVideoXrefID="1000028" PlayListID="1000005" VideoID="1000003" PlayOrder="2"  />
</PlayListVideoXrefs>

<Videos>
<Video VideoID="1000006" StoredFilename="c0739234-b844-46c9-b1b2-96b55f70e17e.mp4" VideoName="barcelona"  />
<Video VideoID="1000003" StoredFilename="50acb2ee-810a-4c32-b097-40c87d253e25.mp4" VideoName="bVideo1"  />
</Videos>
```

I split the Image using Regex and it's not working at all :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<Images[^>]*>(.*?)</Images>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(_strUrl);
ArrayList<String> list_Images = new ArrayList<String>();

try {
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        list_Images.add(m.group(1));

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage().toString(), 1).show();
}
```

Comment: Don't use regex to read XML.  Use DOM or SAX parser.

Comment: can U give me simple for it?

Comment: google "parse XML in android" - you'll get hundreds.  Don't be lazy.

Answer (score 0):

I think Dom can't Work for my XML Beacause image tag contain information that use for dispaly images.me just split image and video tag in two array .
for Split use regex its carefylly work But I want access to Fields in Image tag ..for Example :

```
<Image ImageID="1000032" **StoredFilename**="42825125-8002-4d28-ba90-9889de5e4e91.jpg" ImageName="bPanda"  /></Images>
```

this tag include StoredFiledname that Spilt it in array

Answer (score 0):

To capture the `images` section then you'll probably need to escape the forward slash

`<Images[^>]*>(.*?)<\/Images>`, Live example: http://www.rubular.com/r/h5TZdE5nyb

To parse each of the attributes in a single image tag:

`\s([^=]*)="([^"]*)"`, Live example: http://www.rubular.com/r/eiTS7cpY5p